# Transaction pattern for Azure Table Storage across multiple tables?

Tags: azure, transactions, azure-table-storage

Are there any software patterns that would enable a transaction across multiple tables in Azure Table Storage?

I want to write (or delete) several entities from different tables in atomic way like...

```
try {
  write entity to table A
  write entity to table B
} catch {
  delete entity from table A
  delete entity from table B
}
```

During the above transaction I also want to prevent anyone from writing/deleting the same entities (same table, partition key and row key).

I know Azure Storage does not support this directly so I'm looking for a pattern perhaps using an additional table to "lock" entities in the transaction until its complete.  All writers would have to obtain a lock on the entities.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? When you write the data, is it written through some background process? Do you desire to acquire lock based on the data i.e. when one process is writing the data, same set of data should not be written by any other process or do you want only one process (out of many) to write the data?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to ensure that no one else modifies rows in a table while you are working on them is to add the overhead of blob leasing. You can have the one instance/thread grab the blob lease and do whatever it needs to. Then, when done, release the blob. If it fails to grab the lease, it either has to wait or try again later.
The other table based operations, like pessimistic concurrency, will not actually prevent someone from modifying the records.